# CollectionView "Header" Sticked to the top when scrolling like instagram

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionreusableview

I am wondering how is this achievable?

Perhaps it is best to use an image to explain

[image: Sticky tops]

Can anyone guide me on this please?

Answer (score 0):

I think they have not used Collection View for this. Instead they went for table view and the unscrollable part is table's Section header.
They have customize that section header.

As we know, table section doesn't move until all its rows are out of the View.

So, use table view to achieve desired effect!